# Android: Screen background is set to black when implementing Android Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-xml, android-toolbar

When I implement Android Toolbar on a specific screen/activity on my app called *Register2Activity* (with editText, Radiobuttons and Spinner), the window background color is being set to black. Since I've specified colorPrimary on my AppTheme, blue toolbar and black windowbackground doesn't look good. So, I manually set the windowBackground to white. Now, it looks fine. However, the editText, Radio buttons and spinners are now hidden after I set the windowBackground to white.

**Since the toolbar is blue, I just want a white background on that screen and all the view elements should not be hidden. How am I going to achieve that?**

**styles.xml:** Please see (AppTheme) & (Register2Theme)

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
**<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>

</style>

<style name="Register2Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.delfino.firstup">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_title" />


        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/account_info_title" />

        <activity android:name=".Register2Activity"
                  android:label="User Info"
                  android:theme="@style/Register2Theme"
                  />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**register2_xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    > 


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_register2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"


        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Change your AppTheme to NoActionBar, it will remove the Toolbar and will display your Toolbar

Comment: In register2_xml remove the theme from the parent tag because of that the background color is being set to black.

Comment: Remove `theme` attribute from `register2.xml`. And change `parent="AppTheme"` to your `Register2Theme` style. Your manifest will take care of it.